# Dependency Structure Matrix plugin to analyze C# project in SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, dependency-analysis

Is there a Dependency Structure Matrix tool for C# project in SonarQube. The closet result i found is below, but it is outdated. I know there is one for Java.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/NDeps+Plugin
https://github.com/grozeille/DependencyParser

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been removed for C# projects.

Comment: Is there anything similar in the pipeline or out there which could be a substitute?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But this might come back in the plugin in the future.